# Apigility get Resource name and request method type

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools, zend-framework3

how can i get resource name in Apigility ?
i tried
`$route = $event->getRouteMatch();`
but if resource name contain more than name it split it by .

## example if reouece name "employeeVerifySomething" it  return "employee.verify.something" ?

Also i need to get request type to distinguish between get in "fetch && fetch all "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch them up from in your `onBootstratp()` method of your `module.config.php`. Check out the following method

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $request = $e->getRequest();

    // Get the request method
    $method = $request->getMethod();

    // Get the path according to your format
    $path = $request->getUri()->getPath();
    $parts = explode('/', $path);
    if (!empty($parts)) {
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            $words = preg_split("/((?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?=[A-Z][a-z]))/", $part);
            if (!empty($words)) {
                $words = array_filter($words, function($value, $key){
                    return !empty($value);
                }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
                $words = array_map('strtolower', $words);
            }
            $paths[] = join('.', $words);
        }
    }

    // Here is the formatted path
    $path = join("/", $paths);

    echo $method; // Outputs the requested method for example, GET
    echo $path; // Outputs employee.verify.something against employeeVerifySomething 
}
```

The `$path` variable of the above method would be able to return the formatted resource that you wanted. For example, **"hunkeyPunkey/munkeyDunkeyChunkey"** would be outputted as

```
/hunkey.punkey/munkey.dunkey.chunkey
```

Answer (score 0):

For the point : "Also i need to get request type to distinguish between get in "fetch && fetch all "

For fetch all, with condition, you can overwirte fetch all method

```
$client = new \Zend\Http\Client($uri);
            $client->setMethod('GET');
            $client->setParameterGet(['id'=>1]);

       //Or
        $client->setParameterGet([]);
```

for fetch one or fetch method

add id after url:

```
        $uri.'/'.$id;
```